# Easier way to export only the current group/layer in Sketch?

Tags: export, sketch-app

In Sketch, 99% of the time, when I want to export something, I only want to export the current group or layer. However, whenever I select "Make Exportable", I have to:

1. Find the slice layer at the very top of the layer stack
2. Manually drag it into its group, creating a single-layer group if there is only one layer I want to export
3. Check "Export Group Contents Only"

before I can export just that group or layer. Is there really no faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm used to dragging a group onto desktop to export a PNG file.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. That is indeed the fastest way! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the **[Slice](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/exporting/slices/)** (<kbd>S</kbd>) Tool?

With it you can draw a frame on the canvas which exports the visible content which lies under it.

[image: Sketch slice feature]

Answer (score 1):

Select the group you want to export. In your tools menu on the bottom right there is a CTA for "Make Exportable". Hit that and then all the layers in your group will be set in the slice.

[image]

[image]